# WAR module can't find EJB classes in EJB module in the same EAR

Tags: java-ee-6, glassfish-3, ear, glassfish-4, payara

Well, I have an EAR project with the following structure:

```
EarSample
  - EarSample-ejb.jar
  - EarSample-web.war
```

Inside the EJB module a have a simple stateless session bean with no interfaces (no-view interface).

What's happening is that I'm not being able to inject that EJB in a JSF managed bean packaged in war module. Netbeans not even sees the class.

I've already tried GF 3/4 and Payara.

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Comment: Is the ejb.jar in the build class path of your web.war? If your project is maven based, is the ejb.jar a dependency of web.war project?

Comment: You're right, it's a maven project. I've added EJB module as "provided" dependence and it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as suggested by @OndrejM, I only added EJB-module dependence in WAR's pom.xml as "provided" and it worked perfectly.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>EarSample-ejb</artifactId>
        <version>${project.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: You can mark this answer as the correct answer, even if it is yours ;)

Comment: Considering that it's your answer, I' think you may improve and post it again. So I'd be able to accept and upvote it. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should extract EJB interfaces from EarSample-ejb.jar module and put them into separate jar file EarSample-common.jar. Such archive should be placed in lib folder inside EarSample, so it is reachable from both modules.

Structure should looks like:

```
EarSample
  EarSample-ejb.jar
  EarSample-web.war
  /lib/EarSample-common.jar
```

The reason behind that is compliance with JSR standars, where in general EAR modules should have separate classloaders (which is by default not restricted in Glassfish or JBoss/Wildfly).

If you will extract mentioned EJB interfaces to separate maven module and add that artifact to ejb and web module as compile scope dependencies, your solution will work across all JavaEE 6/7 servers.

Comment: I'm using the no-interface view of EJB.

Comment: To say the truth, adding EJB project as dependence in WAR's pom.xml worked, as suggested by @OndrejM.